# setfacl -m works but setfacl -x does not work

Tags: permissions, setfacl

I have the following code in a bash file:

```
sudo setfacl -m g:jobq:x /usr/local/sbin/jobq_submit
sudo setfacl -m g:jobq:x /usr/local/sbin/jobq_server
sudo setfacl -m g:jobq:x /usr/local/sbin/jobq_server_stop
sudo setfacl -m g:jobq:x /usr/local/sbin/jobq_server_start
sudo setfacl -m g:jobq:x /usr/local/sbin/jobq_status
sudo setfacl -m g:jobq:x /usr/local/sbin/jobq_stop

sudo setfacl -x g:jobq:rw /usr/local/sbin/jobq_submit
sudo setfacl -x g:jobq:rw /usr/local/sbin/jobq_server
sudo setfacl -x g:jobq:rw /usr/local/sbin/jobq_server_stop
sudo setfacl -x g:jobq:rw /usr/local/sbin/jobq_server_start
sudo setfacl -x g:jobq:rw /usr/local/sbin/jobq_status
sudo setfacl -x g:jobq:rw /usr/local/sbin/jobq_stop
sudo setfacl -x g:jobq:rw /usr/local/sbin/jobq_submit
```

The lines with `-m` do not give an error message, but the lines with `-x` say

> setfacl: Option -x: Invalid argument near character 8

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setfacl -x` only takes a reference to the ACL to remove, not the permissions associated with the ACL:

```
sudo setfacl -x g:jobq /usr/local/sbin/jobq_submit
```

Comment: So can we only set full set of permissions, not change one at time?

Comment: Yes, `setfacl -m` takes a full set of permissions for the given ACL; you can’t add `x` and remove `rw` from a given ACL. `setfacl -m g:jobq:x` sets the ACL for group `jobq` to be only `x`.